# React Native Firebase cloud messaging showing notification with no popup / heads up

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i send a notification from my server with the code below, the notification does not show a **heads-up or popup**, it **discreetly** appears in the notification tray:

[image]

here is the code i use to send the notification from the server :

```
let payload = { notification: { title: params.title, body: params.body }};
let options = { 
  priority: "high",
  timeToLive: 60 * 60
};
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(doc.firebase_notif_id, payload, options)
```

here is the version im using in react native:

```
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0"
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you.